# Printing character number i

Tags: counters, characters

I have a counter 1 ≤ *i* ≤ 26 and I want to print a character between *a* and *z* depending on value of *i*. How can I do this in LaTeX?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should write `\alph{cntr}` to get the lowercase latin letter value of `cntr`.

The other similar commands are

- `\alph{cntr}` (lowercase latin)
- `\Alph{cntr}` (uppercase latin)
- `\roman{cntr}` (lowercase roman numeral)
- `\Roman{cntr}` (uppercase roman numeral)
- `\arabic{cntr}` (classical decimal numeral)